# PhoneGap how to refresh/reload page using one page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

Currently, I have a one page app that uses handlebars templates. It has a search function that is controlled by a specific class for that page, the page is /#page/1 then when you click a search result, it takes you to a different page which is controlled by a seperate external class called /#exhibitors/432 (the exhibitor ID is the number at the end).

When i click to go back, and PhoneGap loads the search page (#page/1) in iOS/Safari, unless i reload the entire HTML page using location.reload(), the app will cache the search that was first entered, and it wont take new input.

I have tried to use location.hash to add a random string to the end of the hash, but it will only work when I reload the entire HTML page using location.reload() when the back button is clicked.

There is no issue with Android/Chrome.

Any feedback as to how to reload the HTML and load back the search page which is at #page/1 I would appreciate that. I have tried using location.href = url/#page/1, but it will load the page with none of the dynamic data.

Comment: Have you ever considered using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)? If not, I strongly recommend you to take a look at it, especially [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router). It will help you solve this problem and it will do it in a very neat way. Cheers.

Comment: That is helpful. Thank you for that, I will look into implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

More thoughts on this topic:

1) Rule of thumb is to avoid re-loading the whole HTML page. So how could we achieve this? In your HTML page, you should have a specific DIV, which you manipulate as you see fit. For example, on /#page/1, you should set the content of that DIV whatever #page/1 is supposed to do and when user hits search, then search content should be shown in that field. (Please notice that, I am talking about UI side of things. Actual search could be done by some other service and you can make an AJAX call for that service from your page).

2) You will be listening to all sorts of events (e.g. /#page/1, user hitting search button, server returning search results, or server returning an error message etc). And depending on what is going on, you should decorate that DIV accordingly.

Example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>

    <title>Example</title>


</head>
<body>
<div id="jQUi">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In above HTML, I play with the div with id "content". Here is how:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", letGetGoing, false);

...

function letsGetGoing(){
   $('content').html(useTemplateNamed('page1Template'));
   $('.search').on('change', switchToSearch);
}

function switchToSearch(){
   $('content').html(useTemplateNamed('search'));
   $('.submit').on('change', verifyAndSendToServer);
}
...
```

Above is a pseudo code. I wrote it just to give you an idea.

I hope it helps.